# path is different while running soapui project through maven

Tags: maven, groovy, soapui

Scenario-:

1. I have a shell Script which i have stored inside a directory.
2. The path of the directory is set in the global property of SoapUI.
3. So I am trying to upload the Shell Script upload to remote server through a groovy script .
4. The logic is working fine when I am running the project directly through SoapUI.
5. When I am running the project through maven then I am getting an exception of File not found.

here the groovy script which was used to upload a shell script from local to remote  that groovy script is picking the wrong path wrong local path for shell script all though the shell script storage path is set in the global property .

Here is my pom file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.zaloni.bedrock</groupId>
<artifactId>integration-tests</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>4.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Integration Tests for Bedrock</name>
<url>https://wiki.zaloni.net/index.php?title=Bedrock_Test_Automation</url>
<pluginRepositories>
<pluginRepository>
<id>SmartBearPluginRepository</id>
<url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
</pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi</artifactId>
<version>3.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
<artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
<version>0.1.42</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>dom4j</groupId>
<artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
<version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
<artifactId>soapui-pro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>4.6.1</version>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
<artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
<version>0.9.9-RC1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
<version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi</artifactId>
<version>3.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
<artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
<version>0.1.42</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>dom4j</groupId>
<artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
<version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<executions>
<!--add a new execution block with a different id for each new test xml file-->
<execution>
<phase>integration-test</phase>
<id>Bedrock-4-0-soapui-project.xml</id>
<configuration>
<projectFile>${pom.basedir}/Project_Names/Bedrock-4-0-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
<junitReport>true</junitReport>
</configuration>
<goals>
<goal>test</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Here is the exception what i am getting .'

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\SoapUI_Work\Bedrock_Automation_RestAPI\ShellScriptLib\PreLog_Execute.sh (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
    at Remote_connection.uploadToRemote(Script1.groovy:82)
    at Remote_connection$uploadToRemote.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:33)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:96)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIProGroovyScriptEngineFactory$SoapUIProGroovyScriptEngine.run(SourceFile:89)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:149)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.runTestStep(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:239)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner.runCurrentTestStep(WsdlTestCaseRunner.java:48)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:148)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:43)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestRunner.run(AbstractTestRunner.java:135)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    13:33:11,003 ERROR [log] Unable to Upload Data To Remote Server : An error occurred at uploadToRemote() : null
```

Behavior- ("E:\SoapUI_Work\Bedrock_Automation_RestAPI\bedrock-qa\SOAP_UI_FrameWork_SanitySuite\ShellScriptLib")  is already set in global property  so Groovy script should take this path but  it take  ("E:\SoapUI_Work\Bedrock_Automation_RestAPI/ShellScriptLib") this path so it basically skips 2 directory inside the path .

```
Path set in global property -("E:\SoapUI_Work\Bedrock_Automation_RestAPI\bedrock-qa\SOAP_UI_FrameWork_SanitySuite\ShellScriptLib")

Path is picking -("E:\SoapUI_Work\Bedrock_Automation_RestAPI/ShellScriptLib") "
```

Scripts used in project related to path variables

```
 //Script1
//=======
//Get Project Name
 def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
 def projectDir = groovyUtils.projectPath 
 log.info "Project Directory " + projectDir 

 def mavenBaseDir = ((new java.io.File(projectDir)).getParentFile().getAbsoluteFile())
 log.info "mavenBaseDir-:$mavenBaseDir" 

 //Change the path to get ShellScript Dir( Remote server support only in this way )

  ShellScriptDir=new java.io.File(mavenBaseDir,"ShellScriptLib").toString() 
  log.info "Shell Script Dir:"+ShellScriptDir"

//Script2
//========


  //get Local_Dir_path where Shell Script exist 

  def LocalDir_path = context.expand( '${ShellScriptDir_path}' ) 
  def Remote_Dir_path = "/home/bedrock/Soapui_Automation" 
  Remote_Conn.uploadToRemote(project_IP,
                             22,
                             project_SERVER_USER_ID,
                             project_SERVER_P‌​ASSWORD,
                             LocalDir_path,
                             "PreLog_Execute.sh",
                             Remote_Dir_path)
```

Any solution please .
    Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will not . 
1. If It is working in soapui , soapui is happily finding the path you provided

then when it comes to maven , maven is unable to find the path you provided, that mean you need to point the script file that relative to the maven path

also please check pathSeperator properly , if you have variable in path kindly cross check

in windows C:\\some\\path\\${variableinpath}\\otherfolder   or alternatively C:/some/path/${variableinpath}/otherfolder  you need to use the path

Also could you please try accessing the below path from windows explorer E:\SoapUI_Work\Bedrock_Automation_RestAPI\ShellScriptLib\

**ISSUE**

Also Check this  till "E:\SoapUI_Work\Bedrock_Automation_RestAPI"  is fine after that the slash must be \ but not /

Path is picking -("E:\SoapUI_Work\Bedrock_Automation_RestAPI/ShellScriptLib") "

I hope this answer helps , post your findings.

Comment: If the answer helps dont forget to click answered

Comment: "E:\SoapUI_Work\Bedrock_Automation_RestAPI\ShellScriptLib\"  this the worng path .  It should actually take "E:\SoapUI_Work\Bedrock_Automation_RestAPI\bedrock-qa\SOAP_UI_FrameWork_SanitySuite\ShellScriptLib " which is actually set  in global property . Compare both 2 paths 1st path has actually skipped 2 dir in middle . So that is the main problem why it is skipping 2 dir in between the path .

Comment: can you show me how the script sample how you have used the path inside the script .. please add groovy part of the code in your question, and also can you point me which way you are sending global property through maven.  generally global properties stores in soapui settings.xml , i suspect the maven takes this xml for running , visit soapui settings.xml  that points maven and check the path again

Comment: cross check soapui.log that maven generates  you should see where the settings.xml is pointing to , and also compare soapuisettings.xml where the stand alone soapui.log  pointing to . global properties stores in this place only

Comment: I checked soapui settings.xml here I found it has the correct path and i checked global-groovy.log here i found the wrong path so i believe in run time it's trying set its own path in global property because there is already a groovy script which used to set the absolute for the Shell Script directory in the global property but it is fetching the wrong path in run time and setting that path in the global property in runtime so that might be the reason for the wrong path ... But one thing here when i run the project through soapUI ,its working perfectly .

Comment: We asked you to paste the groovy code that deal with path and global variable that you are accessing.

Comment: My 1st groovy code to set global property "//Get Project Name
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def projectDir = groovyUtils.projectPath log.info "Project Directory " + projectDir . def  mavenBaseDir = ((new java.io.File(projectDir)).getParentFile().getAbsoluteFile())
log.info "mavenBaseDir-:$mavenBaseDir"
//Change the path to get ShellScript Dir( Remote server support only in this way ) ShellScriptDir=new java.io.File(mavenBaseDir,"ShellScriptLib").toString()
log.info "Shell Script Dir:"+ShellScriptDir"  and the another one which use to fetch the path

Comment: //get Local_Dir_path where Shell Script exist def LocalDir_path context.expand( '${ShellScriptDir_path}' )                        
def Remote_Dir_path = "/home/bedrock/Soapui_Automation"
Remote_Conn.uploadToRemote(project_IP,22,project_SERVER_USER_ID,project_SERVER_PASSWORD,LocalDir_path,"PreLog_Execute.sh",Remote_Dir_path)

Comment: You are referring in the second script ${ShellScriptDir_path} , could you please show me where you are setting it . please add that line .. i dont see any where you set a global property in your code. I am assuming ${ShellScriptDir_path} is global property

Comment: See the above one of the script that is setting the Global property . But encountered the problem in my groovy code i have used "//Get Project Name def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context) def projectDir = groovyUtils.projectPath log.info "Project Directory " + projectDir . def mavenBaseDir = ((new java.io.File(projectDir)).getParentFile().getAbsoluteFile()) log.info "mavenBaseDir-:$mavenBaseDir"  So this mavenBaseDir function fetch only the parent dir path but when I run the groovy script through Soapui its working fine but the problem while running through maven

Comment: That is not maven base directory. That is soapui project directory where your soapui project. Xml resides.  groovyUtils.projectPath  refer to your soapui project. Xml and not where maven sits. That's why in stand alone soapui it's passing

Comment: Do you have any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

If the message of the exception claims that there is no such file or directory, then you must verify that the specified is correct and actually points to a file or directory that exists in your system.

Comment: Behavior- ("E:\SoapUI_Work\Bedrock_Automation_RestAPI\bedrock-qa\SOAP_UI_FrameWork_SanitySuite\ShellScriptLib")  is already set in global property  so Groovy script should take this path but  it take  ("E:\SoapUI_Work\Bedrock_Automation_RestAPI/ShellScriptLib") this path so it basically skips 2 directory inside the path .

Path set in global property -("E:\SoapUI_Work\Bedrock_Automation_RestAPI\bedrock-qa\SOAP_UI_FrameWork_SanitySuite\ShellScriptLib")

Path is picking -("E:\SoapUI_Work\Bedrock_Automation_RestAPI/ShellScriptLib") "

Comment: That mean maven picking a path by skipping 2 directory . that mean path is wrong then there is no point of existing file in the location .